# Eclipse Groovy DSLDs and static compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, dsl, subtype

Is it possible to define `Eclipse Groovy DSLD` (DSL Definition) which can be statically compilable?

I tried to use `DSLD` example provided by **Eclipse**, so I created `TestDsl.dsld`:

```
contribute(currentType(subType('groovy.lang.GroovyObject'))) {
    property (
        name : 'newProp',
        type : String,
        provider : 'Sample DSL',
        doc : 'This is a sample.  You should see this in content assist for GroovyObjects: <pre>newProp</pre>')
}
```

Then I wrote a test class using previous property.  This class should be compiled statically. Eclipse is showing new property as a valid one, but then it fails to compile.

[image]
[image]

Same result occurs using both `@CompileStatic` and `@TypeChecked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSLDs introduce new methods and properties into content assist and type inferencing.  This does not guarantee the methods or properties will be available at compile- or run-time.  They operate more like hints than anything.

Quite often, DSLDs are used to fill a gap that exists between the static type checker and the dynamic execution state of your program.  If you want something that is compatible with `@TypeChecked` or `@CompileStatic`, you may need to write a `TypeChekingExtension` instead of a DSLD contribution.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I ended writing a `ASTTransformation` because a `TypeCheckingExtension` was too limited for what I wanted to do.